# scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type; found : package.SomeObject required: Unit

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, sbt, case

I am trying a filesearcher program in scala.

FileChecker.scala

```
package fileSearcher

import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ast.Yield

class FilterChecker(filter:String) {

def matches(content: String) = content contains filter

def findMatchedFiles(fileObjects: List[IOObject]) =

  for(fileObject <- fileObjects
      if(fileObject.isInstanceOf[FileObject])
      if(matches(fileObject.name)))
    yield fileObject

}

object FilterChecker{

  def apply(filter: String)=new FilterChecker(filter)
}
```

IOObject.scala

```
package fileSearcher
import java.io.File
trait IOObject {
  val file:File
  val name= file.getName()
}

case class FileObject(file: File)extends IOObject
case class DirectoryObject(file: File)extends IOObject
```

FileConverter.scala

```
package fileSearcher

import java.io.File

object FileConverter {
def convertToIOObject(file: File){
  if(file.isDirectory()) DirectoryObject(file)
  else FileObject(file)
}
}
```

Matcher.scala

```
package fileSearcher

import java.io.File

class Matcher(filter:String,rootLocation:String) {
val rootIOObject=FileConverter.convertToIOObject(new File(rootLocation))

def execute()={
  val matchedFiles= rootIOObject  match {
    case file : FileObject if FilterChecker(filter) matches file.name =>List(file)  //error 1
    case directory: DirectoryObject => ???    //error 2
    case _ => List()

  }
  matchedFiles map(iOObject => iOObject.name) 
 }
}
```

The above code gives me 2 error.

```
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type; found : fileSearcher.FileObject required: Unit
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type; found : fileSearcher.DirectoryObject required: Unit
```

Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: downvoter please explain the reason?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  Give small but fully-explained example.  How are `convertToIOObject`, `FileObject`, `FilterChecker`, `DirectoryObject`, etc defined?  Without that, it's impossible to tell what your code is doing right or wrong.  For example, I can make up definitions for all those things that make the code compile just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign:

```
def convertToIOObject(file: File) = {
                                  ^
                                  here
```

Without it, the compiler assumes that the method returns `Unit`, which is why the `match` statement was confused: it can't be a `FileObject` or `DirectoryObject` if it has to be a `Unit`.